# Error when using DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 with Docker --mount flag in Bitbucket CI/CD pipeline

Tags: docker, bitbucket, pnpm

I'm encountering an issue when trying to use the `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1` flag in combination with the Docker `--mount` flag within a Bitbucket CI/CD pipeline. My goal is to maximize caching performance when containerizing my application, which relies on PNPM.

Here's the problem I'm facing:

I've set the `DOCKER_BUILDKIT` environment variable to 1 in order to enable the BuildKit features for Docker, as I need to use the `--mount` flag to optimize caching. However, when I run my pipeline, I'm encountering the following error:

```
#4 ERROR: failed to do request: Head "https://10.61.202.23:5000/v2/library/node/manifests/18.17?ns=docker.io": http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client
------
 > [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:18.17:
------
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: failed to do request: Head "https://10.61.202.23:5000/v2/library/node/manifests/18.17?ns=docker.io": http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client
```

Here's the build part of my `Dockerfile` where an error occurs:

```
FROM node:18.17 as build
ENV PNPM_HOME="/pnpm"
ENV PATH="$PNPM_HOME:$PATH"
RUN corepack enable
WORKDIR /opt/app
COPY ./package.json ./pnpm-lock.yaml ./.npmrc ./
RUN --mount=type=cache,id=pnpm,target=/pnpm/store pnpm install --frozen-lockfile --prod
COPY ./ .
RUN pnpm build
```

It seems like there's an issue with accessing a Docker image manifest over HTTPS, but I'm not sure why this is happening specifically in my Bitbucket pipeline. When I build the Docker image locally with the same `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1` flag and `--mount` flag, it works without any errors.

Has anyone else encountered this problem when using Docker BuildKit and the `--mount` flag in a Bitbucket CI/CD pipeline? What could be causing this error, and how can I resolve it to successfully build my Docker image with caching optimizations in my pipeline?